# reactjs regex #xxx#

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like the following:

`Hi. nice to me u#yes me too# umm...`

How do I get the content between two # characters (but does not contain two # symbols) and assign it to the new variable, then delete the contents of the original string##

I am using the reactjs es6 development environment.

Thanks

Comment: You could look into regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like the following.

This will search the input string for patterns that match the `#some string#` pattern, returning an array of matches that exclude '#' characters. To replace the contents between '#' of the original string, you could use the same regular expression with `replace()` as shown:

```js
let input = 'Hi. nice to me u#yes me too#cool##hi there#test umm...';

console.log('input:', input);

// Extract matching substring between # characters
let matches = (input.match(/#[\w\s]+/g) || [])
.map(str => str.replace('#',''))
.filter((str, idx, arr) => arr.length > 0 && idx !== arr.length - 1);

// Replace contents between # characters in original string
input = input.replace(/#[\w\s]+#/g, '')

console.log('between # characters:', matches);
console.log('updated input:', input);
```

Comment: @JasonJiang just updated answer - noticed I missed some detail in your question

Comment: Yes, it can work but haven't delete between #xxx# the original variable , I mean the input inside

Comment: @JasonJiang did you see my updated answer that shows the use of `replace()` ? does that work for you ?

Comment: I mean when the function run done, then the input will be like this    Hi. nice to me u umm...

Comment: @JasonJiang that is what this line does: `input = input.replace(/#[\w\s]+#/g, '')`

Comment: cool man! but if the input have four # E.g: abc#xxy#test#cool# the result will be like this xxy,cool